# Apache Kafka-Zookeeper Properties

Tags: apache-kafka

If i develop a consumer program to consume a message from a topic in the Kafka cluster.

Will the cluster change the offset of the topic that has been created for the message that has been assigned and reassign it somewhere (ie) it computes the offset again and assign it in the partition.

Comment: Is there a reason that you wrote all in bold?

Comment: Nothing specific !!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Offsets are managed by the clients and not by the brokers.

Comment: I think it would be great to salvage a whole section of the docs as an answer, but it would be an overkill, given the question. Have you considered self-answered question and closing this one as a duplicate?